# What happens when a browser closes that can't be programatically replicated?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, authentication

Many authentication services (PHP_AUTH, Apache Basic Auth, SSO services) require that a user's browser be closed to properly/safely terminate their authentication session.

I'm aware some of these services are "stateless" meaning they don't operate on the concept of a "session". Why isn't there a way to simply tell the browser to empty the authentication cache or clear cookies as it would do when it's closed? I've seen a number of hacks for different services to force a "logout", but why are these necessary in the first place?

What happens when a browser closes that can't be replicated through PHP (forcing the server to terminate the session) or JavaScript (forcing the browser to client to terminate, as it would seemingly do when it's closed)? What is the reason these capabilities don't exist (I can only assume they would create some kind of security hole), especially on the client side?

EDIT: As to why I'm asking in this: many times these are the easiest services to set up (If a given organization has single sign-on service with an existing authentication UI, there's no reason to write your own). However, forcing the user to close their entire browser just to arbitrarily log out of a single service seems like something that's clumsy and archaic, and I'm trying to understand what factors determine it has to be this way.

Comment: The browser only sends a request when the page first loads, it doesn't send anything to the server to tell it the user is still viewing the page. Generally systems like that just use session cookie to keep track of a session, or a timeout that logs the user out if nothing is requested for a certain time period.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish or fix here. Nothing tell the server that a user has closed the browser. The session just times out, or the cookie dies.

Comment: With any of services I named, if the browser is closed and then re-opened, the user is forced to re-authenticate. However, there is no way to force the user to re-authenticate with something like a log-out button (unless they close their browser).

Comment: In the latter case the user has to re-authenticate most likely because the site placed a cookie with default lifetime on the client, which will be dropped when the user closes his/her client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public service announcement: Forcing a user to close their browser to logout is a bad user model that will discourage users from logging out, thereby decreasing effective security.

That out of the way...

I suspect that what's happening behind the scenes is that the session ID is maintained in an [HTTP session cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie). These cookies have a lifetime of the current browser session. So when the browser closes, the user loses the association between their browser and their session on the server. The server session hasn't actually terminated, it's just dangling. Presumably it will end when it times out.

So logout is implemented entirely through browser behavior. The app needs to do nothing special.

Besides the aforementioned horrible user model, this solution leaves the session live after the user is done with it. The live session will consume resources and has the chance of being hijacked until it times out. Given these drawbacks, I suspect that this strategy is only used when sessions are implemented on the cheap.

Comment: Forcing users to close the browser was the situation I was in general attempting to avoid, but with the current authentication system, it has proven impossible. Thanks for the insight.